# Custom Summernote toolbar with resize bar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, summernote

I have created a custom Summernote toolbar, but I am having trouble enabling the resize bar with it. It seems only one or the other works.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#summernote').summernote({height: 300});
});

$('#summernote').summernote({
    toolbar: [
        ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
        ['para', ['ul', 'ol']]
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try initializing the editor on document ready, all in one call. You're likely running into issues because you're doing the two separately.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#summernote').summernote({
        height: 300,
        toolbar: [
            ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
            ['para', ['ul', 'ol']]
        ]
    });
});
```